# Finding a parallel algorithm to transpose a matrix

Tags: parallel-computing

> Write a parallel algorithm which runs in $\Theta(n)$ time and transposes an $n \times n$ matrix on the $2D$ mesh *SIMD* Model with wraparound connections. Processing element $P(i, j)$ has local variables $A(i, j)$ and $T(i, j)$, where $1 \leq i, j \leq n$. When the algorithm begins execution $A(i, j) = a(i, j)$. After execution $T(i, j) = a(j, i)$. No processing element should use more than a constant number of variables. Prove that the cost of the algorithm is $\Theta(n)$.

(Question adapted from MJ Quinn book, Parallel Computing Theory and Practice 2nd Edition, Chapter 7).

Comment: (Thumps up for attributing.) Did you just dump an assignment on a community? What good do you think could come of it, and how? If you want your own attempts discussed, present them.

Comment: "I've done the needful" is not something that I understand. And frankly, if you have n^2 processing elements and your algorithm takes Theta(n) time for n^2 operations, then this is a huge waste, and you should instead address the task whose subtask this is.

Comment: @gnasher729 There's a matching lower bound of $\Omega(n)$ since some entries have to travel $\Omega(n)$ steps away.

Comment: Matrix transpose of a mesh is covered in standard texts such as Selim G. Akl's *The Design and Analysis of Parallel Algorithms*.

Comment: To @greybeard and others:
I need to find a solution where the 2D mesh SIMD Model has wraparound connections. I can not find a solution and I also searched but I did not find it. I have just read the theory and I am having difficulty in finding the algorithm on my own. If I cannot get an answer even though the problem is pretty "standard" according to you all, what is the use of this community anyways? Are all the questions asked here before pretty "out of the box" as you all suggest?